# How to translate language localization into Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, information-technology

**I would like a translation of the title in**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really many languages base themself on `local`, Esperanto `loka`. Now `lokaĵaro` is the technical programming term `locale` [Reta Vortaro]. Probably as `lokalo` and `lokalizi` already cover a specific side notion.

> **lokaĵigado** = localization

Comment: I've always seen [lokaĵaro](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka%C4%B5aro) as the translation. `Lokaĵo` is a single parameter, for example the date format or the decimal separator. `Locale` is always about the group of such settings (in computer software).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani true.

Comment: Lingva lokaĵigado seems to me a good cultural-linguistic translation / adaptation to the local language community.

Comment: But `lokaĵigado` doesn't really work. As said before, you are working with a `lokaĵaro`, not with the single parameters. You cannot remove the `-aro` and tack the `-ig` at the end, hoping it will still mean `lokaĵaro`.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani _lokaĵigado_ would function for _lokaĵaro_ too.

Comment: `lokaĵigado`, krom la supre menciitaj problemoj, estas ankaŭ peza kaj malfacile analizebla. Eble tial _-aĵig-_ ne estas vere multe uzata (kontroleblas en Tekstaro).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani pro la ideo de E-o kiel _dua lingvo_, mi persone bedaŭras ke ne ekzistas flekseblo por pligrandigi la difinon de lokal/o, lokaliz/i ĉar intertempe tio estas la normo inter dekoj da lingvoj (eĉ se la laiko iom devas konjekti pri la signifo). `lokaĵigado` ne havas fluan prononcon. Tute alia vorto nur eblus se jam uzita kun la sama signifo en alia kampo. _localisation_ je estas faka kampo. Tamen la vorto malagrable kontrastus kun la alilingvaj tradukoj.

Comment: @JoopEggen la difino en la angla estas "Localizaton is the process of adapting ... to a specific country or region".  PIV havas tiun ekzemplon en _adapt/_ (citita en mia propono). Mi bedaŭras ke, pro tiu ĉi respondo, oni kreis artikolon en Vikipedio kun la nomo [lokaĵigado](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka%C4%B5igado_(lingva)). Kelkfoje oni penas krei _pseudoteknikan_ radikon kiam la ekzistantaj jam sufiĉas. _adapt/_ laŭ PIV estus trafa, taŭga kaj komprenebla, sen devi lerni ion novan aŭ speguli aliajn lingvojn. Se oni volus nepre uzi _lok/_, _lokumado_ estus eble pli bona ol _lokaĵigado_.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani mi komprenas vian senton, mi same sentas pri la venkinta _bildrastrumero_ anstataŭ _pikselo_. Por ke Esperanto estu internacia, teknikaj nocioj estas neeviteble. Do kvankam _(etna) adaptado_ eble taŭgus, internacia rekoneblo el la starpunkto de neesperantisto same gravas.

Answer (score 1):

Localization supposes the existence of a *locale* (country, region, ethnic group, ...).

It is an adaptation. Please don't use *asimili* for *localization*!

I would go with:

```
adapt/
```

for example

```
lingva/regiona/etna adapto
```

But note that in cases where *just* the language is taken into account (and not the country, region...), it might also make sense to talk about *translation*.

I would like to add a definition of [adapti](http://vortaro.net/#adapti) (konformigi al specialaj celoj aŭ kondiĉoj) and one of the examples provided:

> adapti teatraĵon (ĝin modifi, por faciligi ĝian sukceson ĉe alikultura
>   publiko).

Comment: Esperantujo counts as a locale for me, but yes, _adapt/_.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas Good point. Since from a technical point of view every language is a locale, I changed the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Komputeko lists *"asimili"*](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=lokalise) for *"to localize"* / *"to localise"*.

"Localisation" (the process) could thus be *"asimilado"*.

In a sentence with enough context this could work. But as an article title, it has to be able to stand on its own, and the various [other (non-IT) meanings of *"asimili"*](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/asimili) would get into our way. Trying to more precisely specify it with "lingve" or "lingva", similar to the English expression, as some of the non-IT meanings can also apply to languages and / or language adoption.

Answer (score 0):

Jen estas utila (sed ne plena) fonto por serĉi jam uzitajn tradukojn. https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=localization. "Adapti" aŭ "agordi" ankaŭ taŭgus. Ŝajnas, ke mi jam vidis ie jam "lingvaj agordoj" en senco "Language localisation", sed la kuntekso temas pri elekto de uzanto sed ne pri laboro por asimiligo de programkreanto.